# Ошибка в базе данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

> Warning: #1265 Data truncuted for column 'cart_ip' at row 1.

Хотел добавить в эту запись ip `127.0.0.1` так как работаю на локальной машине и тут ошибка. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Покажите create table и какой запрос приводит к ошибке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы задали длину столбца `cart_ip` меньше, чем пытаетесь вставить. Например, возможно, объявили как `varchar(6)`, а должно быть 15.

Соответственно, надо провести `ALTER TABLE` и изменить длину столбца на нужную. На бОльшую.

Пример:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable CHANGE cart_ip cart_ip VARCHAR(15);
```

> Да нет у меня стоит int(100)

Так тем более для ip надо менять тип поля. Ибо строка чаров в int не влезет, однако.

Comment: Да нет у меня стоит int(100)...

Comment: Стоит int(100), а вы вводите строку? Серьезно, вас ничего не смущает?

Comment: Спасибо, Nizazu, за ответ. Я ещё учусь

Comment: @OlexandrPylypyshyn меняйте тип поля на корректный

Comment: Так и сделал. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы хранить IP в бд в виде числа, нужно его преобразовать с помощью `INET_ATON`, что в принципе правильнее, чем хранить строку. Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)